# HTML include navigation elements with relative links

Tags: javascript, html

I included a navigation element in multiple pages like this:
`<script> $(function(){ $("#includedNavigation").load("navigation.html"); }); </script>`

But this works just for html-files in the same directory "subdir". The navigation.html cannot be reached from the index.html in the upper main directory "dir".
If I add the upper pattern to the `index.html` in the directory above the `navigation.html` is reached correctly but the relative links do not work anymore. I don't want to replace the relative links by absolute paths.
Is it possible to switch between different links in `navigation.html`depending on wherefrom it is called?
Any other ideas?
Thanks a lot!

[image: Draft]

Comment: All pages that use navigation.html should have their directory structured in the same way for relative paths to work. If only one page uses navigation.html, just change all the relative links inside it to be relative to index.html directory structure instead of navigation.html directory structure. Got any example link from navigation.html and the directory trees we can see?

Comment: @Shilly . thanks. I added a sketch to clarify the construction.

Comment: All pages shall have the same menu. So all contain: `   <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedNavigation").load("navigation.html"); 
    });
    </script> ` and `<div id="includedNavigation"></div>` .

Comment: The easy solution is to make sure than index.html and all the pages are in the same directory so they can all use "./pageX.html". Since this is a multiple page website that reuses the same menu on all its pages, there's no functional or logical difference between page1 and index apart from index probably being the first page you see. So I would just put index.html in the same folder and call it a day. It would make sense to have it on an upper level if the index page would load all the other pages into itself. Then the menu would only need to be included on the index page.

Comment: Well, that sounds quite practical. But the grouping in folders helps to give a clear overview, e.g. to distinct pages by means of the topic.

Comment: That's very true, but also kind of a logical fallacy. It's a project requirement, not a technical requirement. In development, all of our page are likewise divided into sub directories and such to organize the files. But when we run the deployment script to copy everything into production, the deploy script concatenates everything into one file anyway and the entire folder structure disappear. It's perfectly normal to have a clear folder structure for development organised by business needs and also have a completely different folder structure for live code organised by technical needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190851/discussion-between-peng-and-shilly).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a multiple page website that reuses the same menu on all its pages, there's no functional or logical difference between `page1.html` and `index.html` apart from index probably being the first page you see. So I would just put index.html in the same folder and call it a day. It would make sense to have it on an upper level if the index page would load all the other pages into itself. Then the menu would only need to be included on the index page.

A folder structure is a project requirement, not a technical requirement. In development, all pages are likewise divided into sub directories and such to organize the files. But with running the deployment script to copy everything into production, the deploy script concatenates everything into one file anyway and the entire folder structure disappear.

It's perfectly normal to have a clear folder structure for development organised by business needs and also have a completely different folder structure for live code organised by technical needs.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the path of navigation.html file.

$(function(){ $("#includedNavigation").load("./dir/navigation.html"); });

like this

Comment: @gaurav_krishna : there is no problem to include the navigation.html in the subdir. But from the perspective of `index.html` there is no `./page1.html` as it is for `page2.html` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this

```
<link rel="import" href="navigation.html">
```

Or

```
$(function(){ $("#includedNavigation").load("path/to/navigation.html"); });
```

Comment: @Staphan_Golubev : Thanks for your answer. I tried the second alternative. I can include `navigation.html` from every directory but the relative links inside of `navigation.html` do not work anymore because the path is relative to the calling file, and not fixed to `navigation.html`.